# Conditional Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to Rails, so bear with me while I learn.

I have a model, `show`, with an attribute `preview_url`. How can I build a call that only returns `shows` that have a non-null `preview_url` and what would be the best way to word the controller method?

i.e. localhost:3000/shows/?preview_url ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read a book on rails. That'll give you structured knowledge and save you (and us) some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ShowsController` you would have an action named `with_preview` like this:

```
def with_preview
  @shows = Show.where('preview_url IS NOT NULL').all
end
```

The url for this action would be `/shows/with_preview`

Comment: I am getting `Couldn't find Show with id=with_preview` when I try this. I have the standard `index` and `show` methods in place.

Comment: Good practice would be creating a named scope on your model. So you would do Show.whith_preview.all. So if you do need that condition in another controller action you don't need to repeat the where clause.